# How to delete millions of records with dependency on other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three table

Table 1 with Primary key Element_ID

Table 2 with Primary Key Structure_ID

Table 3 with primary key MOD_ELEMENT and there are two foreign Element_ID (from table1) and Structure_ID (from table 2).

I have got the Element_id and structure_id from query that needs to be deleted so I have to delete data from table 3 first and then the other two table. Total number of records to be deleted are more than 10 million.

Using a cursor will be an expensive operation in case I am iterating over the values to be deleted.

Comment: [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

/*delete any data from table3 that references the ids to be deleted*/
Delete from table3 where Element_ID in elementids or Structure_ID in structureids;

--then delete table2 and table1 data
Delete from table2 where Structure_ID in structureids;

Delete from table1 where Element_ID in elementids;

Comment: It looks like it removed the asterisk symbols from the sql comment.